# CodeKit app and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Anybody has problem in compiling rails HAML files using CodeKit app. CodeKit considers rails ERB wrong syntax! what is the solution.

Comment: It would be nice to post the actual error message.It will help folks to locate the problem easily.

Comment: The tool does not give me specific error. it always gives error when haml has ruby code embedded in it!